# Optimizing Wordle Bot with Python - Search for a word that contains a, b, and c?

Tags: python, optimization, wordle-game

I have been working on writing a Wordle bot, and wanted to see how it preforms with all 13,000 words. The problem is that I am running this through a for loop and it is very inefficient. After running it for 30 minutes, it only gets to around 5%. I could wait all that time, but it would end up being 10+ hours. There has got to be a more efficient way. I am new to python, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The code here is the code that is used to limit down the guesses each time. Would there be a way to search for a word that contains "a", "b", and "c"? Instead of running it 3 separate times. Right now the containts, nocontains, and isletter will each run every time I need to search for a new letter. Searching them all together would greatly reduce the time.

```py
#Find the words that only match the criteria
def contains(letter, place):
    list.clear()
    for x in words:
        if x not in removed:
            if letter in x:
                if letter == x[place]:
                    removed.append(x)
                else:
                    list.append(x)
            else:
                removed.append(x)
def nocontains(letter):
    list.clear()
    for x in words:
        if x not in removed:
            if letter not in x:
                list.append(x)
            else:
                removed.append(x)
def isletter(letter, place):
    list.clear()
    for x in words:
        if x not in removed:
            if letter == x[place]:
                list.append(x)
            else:
                removed.append(x)
```

Comment: Don't use list as a variable name, its a keyword.

Comment: Can you also include where `words` and `list` (+1 to kpie btw, use a different name) are defined?

Comment: @kingkupps
`my_file = open("allowed-answers.txt", "r")`

`words = my_file.readlines()`

`list = []`
`removed = []`

allowed-guesses is the text file with the 13,000 words

Comment: @kpie Ok I will fix that

Comment: There are a lot of optimizations and improvements possible. Most of the performance problems come from using Python lists exclusively, when most of your data structures should probably be [sets or dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). It also looks like you're *exclusively* using global variables, which is not the best. While this question is on-topic and welcome here, you might also benefit from posting your code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since the code is working but slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance problems can be massively reduced by using [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). Any time that you want to repeatedly test for membership (even only a few times), e.g. `if x not in removed`, you want to try to make a set. Lists require checking every element to find x, which is bad if the list has thousands of elements. In a Python set, `if x not in removed` should take as long to run if `removed` has `100` elements or `100,000`, a small constant amount of time.

Besides this, you're running into problems by trying to use mutable global variables everywhere, like for `list` (which needs to be renamed) and `removed`. There's no benefit to doing that and several downsides, such as making it harder to reason about your code or optimize it. One benefit of Python is that you can pass large containers or objects to functions without any extra time or space cost: calling a function `f(huge_list)` is as fast and uses as much memory as `f(tiny_list)`, as if you were passing by reference in other languages, so don't hesitate to use containers as function parameters or return types.

In summary, here's how your code could be refactored if you take away 'list' and 'removed' and instead store this as a `set` of possible words:

```py
all_words = []  # Huge word list to read in from text file
current_possible_words = set(all_words)

def contains_only_elsewhere(possible_words, letter, place):
    """Given letter and place, remove from possible_words
     all words containing letter but not at place"""
    to_remove = {word for word in possible_words
                 if letter not in word or word[place] == letter}
    return possible_words - to_remove

def must_not_contain(possible_words, letter):
    """Given a letter, remove from possible_words all words containing letter"""
    to_remove = {word for word in possible_words
                 if letter in word}
    return possible_words - to_remove

def exact_letter_match(possible_words, letter, place):
    """Given a letter and place, remove from possible_words
     all words not containing letter at place"""
    to_remove = {word for word in possible_words
                 if word[place] != letter}
    return possible_words - to_remove
```

The outside code will be different: for example,

```py
current_possible_words = exact_letter_match(current_possible_words, 'a', 2)`
```

Further optimizations are possible (and much easier now): storing only indices to words rather than the strings; precomputing, for each letter, the set of all words containing that letter, etc.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I just implemented these and it works so much faster than it was before! This is my first time using StackOverflow, and I really appreciate the explanation and examples.

Comment: @Zapzival Sure thing, most of these are hard to figure out when you're new to Python. It also helps that things were broken down into small functions. I'd still recommend also visiting the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange. Some improvements, like using classes and breaking things down into smaller functions, are better explained in a full code review, and will make writing a full Wordle bot significantly easier.

Comment: Ok, will do. Before the bot ran 13,000 words in 10+ hours, which I didn't finish after running only 10% after 1 hour. Now it did it in 3 minutes! I will definitely be looking at the website as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a wordle bot that runs in about a second including the web scraping to fetch a list of 5 letter words.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getwords():
    source = "https://www.thefreedictionary.com/5-letter-words.htm"
    filehandle = urllib.request.urlopen(source)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(filehandle.read(), "html.parser")
    wordslis = soup.findAll("li", {"data-f": "15"})
    words = []
    for k in wordslis:
        words.append(k.getText())
    return words

words = getwords()

def hasLetterAtPosition(letter,position,word):
    return letter==word[position]

def hasLetterNotAtPosition(letter,position,word):
    return letter in word[:position]+word[position+1:]

def doesNotHaveLetter(letter,word):
    return not letter in word

lettersPositioned = [(0,"y")]
lettersMispositioned = [(0,"h")]
lettersNotHad = ["p"]

idx = 0
while idx<len(words):
    eliminated = False
    for criteria in lettersPositioned:
        if not hasLetterAtPosition(criteria[1],criteria[0],words[idx]):
            del words[idx]
            eliminated = True
            break
    if eliminated:
        continue
    for criteria in lettersMispositioned:
        if not hasLetterNotAtPosition(criteria[1],criteria[0],words[idx]):
            del words[idx]
            eliminated = True
            break
    if eliminated:
        continue
    for letter in lettersNotHad:
        if not doesNotHaveLetter(letter,words[idx]):
            del words[idx]
            eliminated = True
            break
    if eliminated:
        continue
    idx+=1

print(words) # ["youth"]
```

The reason yours is slow is because you have a lot of calls to check if word in removed in addition to a number of superfluous logical conditions in addition to going through all the words for each of your checks.

Edit: Here's a get words function that gets more words.

```
def getwords():
    source = "https://wordfind-com.translate.goog/length/5-letter-words/?_x_tr_sl=es&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp"
    filehandle = urllib.request.urlopen(source)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(filehandle.read(), "html.parser")
    wordslis = soup.findAll("a", {"rel": "nofollow"})
    words = []
    for k in wordslis:
        words.append(k.getText())
    return words
```

Comment: Thank you! I will be working on implementing that and fixing up the logic that I use.

Comment: Your web pull is only getting 499 words out of 150K, check `len(words)`.  Also, if pulling things out of a collection, you should really be using sets rather than lists, muuuuuch faster.